# Relative pronoun for "fois"

Tags: pronoms-relatifs

> C'est la deuxieme fois ___ elle a oublié de faire ses devoirs.

What can go into the blank? Is it the relative pronoun *où* which is often used for times? Do *quand*, *que*, *pendant laquelle*, and *à laquelle* all not work?

Comment: The sentence construction itself is not correct as is. Change it to: "ça/cela  fait deux fois que" or "c'est {ça/cela  fait} la deuxième fois que".

Comment: Just changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct way of saying it : C'est la deuxieme fois *qu'elle* a oublié de faire ses devoirs.

**où** : (from http://www.linternaute.com/dictionnaire/fr/definition/ou-1/)

Sens 1 -  L'endroit où.
Exemple : Il n'a pas à me dire où je dois aller.
English : where

Sens 2 - Le moment où.
Synonyme : quand
English : when

Sens 3 - Marque la conséquence.
Exemple : D'où ma surprise quand j'ai appris la nouvelle.

**Quand** :
It is mostly used for "when"

*Quand* es-tu parti ?
*When* did you leave?

**Que** :
It is equivalent to "that"

C'est dommage *qu*'il ne soit pas prêt.

It's too bad (that) he's not ready.

Note that "that" is optional in English, but "que" cannot be omitted.

**Pendant laquelle** :
Can be used for when / during which / in which / over which
It is usually use to express time.

Définissez la période *pendant laquelle* le profil de journée est actif.

Define the period *when* the day profile is active.

**à laquelle** :
Equivalent to which / that / to which

La question à laquelle certaines personnes avaient répondu.

The question to which a few people had answered.

Answer (score 1):

Right answer is:

> C'est la deuxième fois qu'elle a oublié de faire ses devoirs.

There is no really other way to say that.